# How to detect already connected USB drive?

Tags: macos, usb

I am using a MacMini runing OS/X for some work, and I'm n00b to OS/X - and I often leave a USB drive plugged in when I switch off at night.

However, when I re-start, the drive is not detected and needs to be unplugged and plugged back in.

Is there a way to force the Mac to re-detect the drive?

Comment: For anyone searching who's a Win user and new to Mac - you "mount" drives in OS/X (and all *nix type OS's)